# Questions about Rabbitmq

Tags: memory

guys.

If anyone knows about Rabbitmq, could you help me?

Our company is using Rabbitmq as a cluster.

By the way, every time the node server restarts, it fills up the memory, issues a warning, and blocks messages.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Rabbitmq is operating in a container using a docker.

Server specifications are 2 cores and 2GB Ram.

AWS's T3.Small size.

No matter what I did, I couldn't solve this problem.

I wish I had someone who could give me a little clue.

Comment: You are (apparently) encountering high memory watermarks. "High memory watermark blocks publishers and prevents new messages from being enqueued." Likewise, memory usage can double during garbage collection. You should probably start by using RabbitMQ to relay information back to you about its memory usage then compare that with other system data to detect any common issues like connection leaks or enqued messages without consumers (both application specific behaviors). Generally speaking,   RabbitMQ recommends many queues and (at least in instances where message sizes are large) lazy queues.